# Set date format of JqueryUI Datepicker based on Browser setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I created a function to prepare all setting for Datepicker . You can see it below ,it run perfect but my customer want change dateformat based on browser setting .I searched in stackoverflow and found some topic about this .But every topic talk about set dateformat based on server not by broswer.So please teach me how i can get dateformat from broswer or system dateformat so i can set it to dateformat of Datepicker .Thank you and sorry about my english if not clearly please feedback and i will answer, thank you for read .

```
function setupDatepicker() {

$.datepicker.regional['translated'] = {
    prevText: '<',
    nextText: '>',
    currentText: '-',
    monthNames: [
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_january'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_february'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_march'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_april'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_may'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_june'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_july'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_august'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_september'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_october'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_november'),
        i18n.t('Translations::label_common_month_december')],
    monthNamesShort: [
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_jan'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_feb'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_mar'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_apr'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_may'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_jun'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_jul'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_aug'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_sep'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_oct'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_nov'),
        i18n.t('Translations::month_short_dev')],
    dayNames: [
        i18n.t('Translations::day_mon'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_tue'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_wed'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_thu'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_fri'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_sat'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_sun')],
    dayNamesShort: [
        i18n.t('Translations::day_short_mon'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_short_tue'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_short_wed'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_short_thu'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_short_fri'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_short_sat'),
        i18n.t('Translations::day_short_sun')],
    **dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'**,//i want set browser dateFormat here.
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''};
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {

    },
    prevText: '<',
    nextText: '>',
    minDate: 1
});

$.datepicker.setDefaults(
    $.datepicker.regional['translated']
);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Why do not you use coockie os local storage to save settings to user browser ?

Comment: But in fact i only need get DateFormat from Region setting .You can see it has shortdate format option in there. I just need to get that format and apply it to my code .I know javascript have .toLocaleDateString() function to get day based on locale and time zone .But i need dateformat of that day which i get from toLocaleDateString() .Thank for your rely